# Remove NFC Tag in Python

Tags: python, nfc, lego-mindstorms

I got my hands on a Lego Dimensions pad which is in fact a triple NFC reader. Found some code on [github](https://github.com/VincentXE/Lego-Dimensions-Pad-Scripts) to start playing with it with a raspberry pi. I've got it so far that it sends a webhook to my Home Assistant to turn on a light when placing a minifigure on the pad. Where I got stuck and my python programming skills fall short is to also send a webhook when the tag is removed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thx!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import usb.core
import usb.util
from time import sleep
import requests

TOYPAD_INIT = [0x55, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x01, 0x28, 0x63, 0x29, 0x20, 0x4c, 0x45, 0x47, 0x4f, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x34, 0xf7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]

# Colors
OFF   = [0,0,0]
RED   = [255,0,0]
GREEN = [0,255,0]
BLUE  = [0,0,255]
YELLOW = [255,255,0]
PURPLE = [128,0,128]

# Pad number
ALL_PADS   = 0
CENTER_PAD = 1
LEFT_PAD   = 2
RIGHT_PAD  = 3

# Actions
TAG_INSERTED = 0
TAG_REMOVED  = 1

# UIDs can be retrieved with Android App (most probably in hexadecimal)
uidBatman = [4, 117, 251, 42, 41, 73, 128] # Batman Lego
uidLucy = [4, 66, 84, 114, 82, 66, 129] # Lucy Lego
uidGandalf = [4, 133, 184, 90, 181, 73, 128] # Gandalf

# Webhook var
auth_token='[Token]'
hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}
dataon = {"state": "on"}
dataoff = {"state": "off"}

def init_usb():
    global dev

    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0e6f, idProduct=0x0241)

    if dev is None:
        print("Device not found")
    else:
        if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0):
            dev.detach_kernel_driver(0)

        print usb.util.get_string(dev, dev.iProduct)

        dev.set_configuration()
        dev.write(1,TOYPAD_INIT)

    return dev

def send_command(dev,command):

    # calculate checksum
    checksum = 0
    for word in command:
        checksum = checksum + word
        if checksum >= 256:
            checksum -= 256
        message = command+[checksum]

    # pad message
    while(len(message) < 32):
        message.append(0x00)

    # send message
    dev.write(1, message)

    return

def switch_pad(pad, colour):
    send_command(dev,[0x55, 0x06, 0xc0, 0x02, pad, colour[0], colour[1], colour[2],])
    return

def main():
    init_usb()
    if dev != None :
        while True:
            try:
                in_packet = dev.read(0x81, 32, timeout = 10)
                bytelist = list(in_packet)

                if not bytelist:
                    pass
                elif bytelist[0] != 0x56: # NFC packets start with 0x56
                    pass
                else:
                    pad_num = bytelist[2]
                    uid_bytes = bytelist[6:13]
                    action = bytelist[5]
                    if action == TAG_INSERTED :
                        print uid_bytes
                        if (uid_bytes == uidBatman) :
                            switch_pad(pad_num, RED)
                            url = '[URL]'
                            response = requests.post(url, json=dataon, headers=hed)
                            print(response)
                            print(response.json())
                        elif (uid_bytes == uidLucy) :
                            switch_pad(pad_num, PURPLE)
                            url = '[URL]'
                            response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=hed)
                            print(response)
                            print(response.json())
                        elif (uid_bytes == uidGandalf) :
                            switch_pad(pad_num, YELLOW)
                            url = '[URL]'
                            response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=hed)
                            print(response)
                            print(response.json())
                        else:
                            # some other tag
                            switch_pad(pad_num, GREEN)
                    else:
                        # some tag removed
                        switch_pad(pad_num, OFF)

            except usb.USBError, err:
                pass

        switch_pad(ALL_PADS,OFF)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It seems you need to do something similar to `if action == TAG_INSERTED`. I have no idea, but did you try using `if action == TAG_REMOVED`?

Comment: Or adding some code where the comment says `# some tag removed`?

Comment: Yes I tried and it didn't work. TAG_REMOVED variable cannot be right, nothing is triggered when a tag is removed. I should probably do something with WHILE.

Comment: I can only add one action to  # some tag removed . I need to perform an action per individual tag